# APK works on Samsung but in Nexus giving 2 errors?

Tags: android, android-studio

In my app, first a create a NewFolder, and then i record audios and save them inside this new folder.
 I also have a ArrayList to show my Records
Here I create the NewFolder

```
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    String sep = File.separator; // Use this instead of hardcoding the "/"
    String newFolder = "FolderName";
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myNewFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + sep + newFolder);
    //myNewFolder.mkdir();
    myNewFolder.mkdirs();


    while (fs.getfetchstatus() != true) {
        mySongs = fs.findSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()); 
              //>>>>>>>>>>HERE IS HAVING ANY ERROR<<<<<<<<<


    }
    if (mySongs != null) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    mySongs = fs.getsonglist();

    items = new String[mySongs.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < mySongs.size(); i++) {
        items[i] = mySongs.get(i).getName().toString().replace(".3gp", "");

    }
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(adp);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Player.class);
            intent.putExtra("pos", i);
            adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

here is my ArrayList

```
     boolean fetchstatus=false;
ArrayList<File> songs=new ArrayList<File>();

String sep = File.separator; // Use this instead of hardcoding the "/"
String newFolder = "FolderName";
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myNewFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + sep + newFolder);

//File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
FetchSongs(){

}
public ArrayList<File> findSongs(File root){

    ArrayList<File> al=new ArrayList<File>();
   // File[] files=root.listFiles();

    //File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), newFolder);
    File[] files = file.listFiles();


    for (File singleFile : files){
        if(singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()){
            al.addAll(findSongs(singleFile));
    //>>>>>>>ERROR HERE<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

        }
        else {
            if(singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3")){
                al.add(singleFile);
            }
        }
    }

    fetchstatus=true;
    songs=al;
    return al;

}
```

I'm having these errors

```
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
    at org.usr.usr.musicplayer.FetchSongs.findSongs(FetchSongs.java:35)
                                                                   at org.usr.usr.musicplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:124)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's just this line the error

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), newFolder);
```

Nexus not always has got an external storage, but to be more accurate you should check the trace error, most likely you'll be able to see the exactly lines that cause the runt time error

Comment: in the FetchSongs the line the error is where i have the FOR

Comment: for (File singleFile : files){

Comment: That's because in the for there are no check against files to see if it null or not.

Comment: Write something like this, if(files!=null && files.length>0){for(File singleFile : files){.....}}

Comment: you did it!, saved my time, my error now is just when i record the audio, thank you !

Comment: You can also try to debug your code, just put a breakpoint 2-3 lines before the error and analyze the content of your variables